# How can I get access to the ecobee switch+ data via the api

Tags: ecobee-api

I was wondering how can I get access or get pushed data from the switch+. The api docs don’t contain any information on the switch.

Comment: Seems like the Ecobee developers sure are monitoring stack overflow and care about providing developer resources to those interested in adding value to the platform.